# I need show products with zero prices in end of collection

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I take the product collection in observer of catalog_block_product_list_collection event

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Itdelight_Sorting>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
        </Itdelight_Sorting>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <sorting>
                <class>Itdelight_Sorting_Block</class>
            </sorting>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <sorting>
                <class>Itdelight_Sorting_Model</class>
            </sorting>
        </models>
       <events>
            <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <observers>
                    <options>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Itdelight_Sorting_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sort</method>
                    </options>
                </observers>
            </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
       </events>
    </global> 
</config>
```

And in file Observer in sort function I need to create an sql expression to this collection but I don't know how do it.

```
class Itdelight_Sorting_Model_Observer {

    /**
     * 
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function sort(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $collection = $event->getCollection();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add an expression to determine if the value is zero priced or not and then add a sort by. Problem is going to user selected sort in frontend which might need to be looked at. Not tested but something like this might do it.

```
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('zero_price', 'IF(price = 0, 1, 0)');
$collection->getSelect()->order('zero_price ASC');
```

You can output the sql query using `var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString()); die();` for debugging the sql.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work I will try to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. I rewrote toolbar block and added code:

```
 public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            if(($this->getCurrentDirection()=='asc')){
                 $this->_collection->getSelect()->columns(array('price_zero' => new Zend_Db_Expr('IF(price_index.price > 0,price_index.price, 9999999)')));
                 $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('price_zero ASC');
            }else{
                $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
            }

            }

        return $this;
    }
```

Thanks for help :)